# Выровнять изображение по вертикали в Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, internet-explorer

```css
main .home {
    width: 100%;
    height: 900px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(320deg, #fffbf2 10px, transparent 11px), 
        linear-gradient(40deg, #fffbf2 10px, transparent 11px), url(http://s8.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/images/2016/05/7b91cf406f7189d8c9b10731e7ec4569.jpg); 
    background-repeat:  repeat-x, repeat-x, no-repeat;
    background-size: 15px 15px, 15px 15px, 100% 100%;
    background-position: bottom, bottom;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    justify-content: center;
}

main .home .main_photo {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(http://s8.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/images/2016/05/951888c43a4981f879acab8cf1b52d27.png) no-repeat center;
}

main .home .logo_first_header,
main .home .logo_second_header {
    font-family: black-coffee;
background-color: #333333;
color: #fffccc;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: auto;
}

main .home .logo_first_header {
    margin-top: -370px;
}

main .home .logo_second_header {
    margin-top: -250px;
}
```

```html
<main>
            <section class="home" id="home">
                <div class="main_photo"></div>
                <p class="logo_first_header">A RETROSPECTIVE DESIGN WITH A GOOD TASTE</p>
                <p class="logo_second_header">SIMPLE. CREATIVE. VINTAGE.</p>
            </section>
</main>
```

Нужно расположить блоки с картинкой и текстом по центру. Во всех браузерах всё работает нормально, но в IE часть CSS-свойств просто игнорируется. Для поднятия логотипа и текста вверх использовал отрицательный `margin-top`.

Должно быть так:
[image: во всех браузерах]

В IE получается так:
[image: в IE]

Как сделать центрирование блоков по вертикали в IE?

Comment: Можно использовать CSS3 flexbox, если вам нужна поддержка в IE 10-11. Если же необходима поддержка версий пораньше, то можно попробовать `display: table` для родительского элемента и `display: table-cell` для дочернего. Также, было бы неплохо приложить к ответу HTML код.

Comment: А можно немного больше кода в виде сниппета/фиддла? И вообще, я бы совсем по-другому это делал.

Comment: добавил код в основной вопрос, подскажите пожалуйста, как можно это исправить в IE?

Comment: опять версию IE не написали. для какого вам надо, для IE6?

Comment: начиная с 8ого и выше

Answer (score 1):

Если вам нужно выровнять блок по вертикали другого блока, я бы посоветовал вам эти способы выравнивания:

#### 1. Решение через Flexbox

```css
.container-fluid {
  height: 400px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  
  display: flex;
  /* Центрируем по вертикали */
  align-items: center;
  /* Центрируем по горизонтали */
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5 text-center ">
      <div class="play-btn">
        <img src="http://elzol.lamusica.com/images/core/play.png" alt="Play">
        <p>Some Button</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### 2. Решение через псевдоэлемент с поддержкой IE 9

```css
.container-fluid {
  height: 400px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Обертка */
.container-fluid:before {
   content: '';
   height: 100%;
   display: inline-block !important;
   vertical-align: middle;
}

/* Блок, который нужно выровнять */
.row {
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5 text-center ">
      <div class="play-btn">
        <img src="http://elzol.lamusica.com/images/core/play.png" alt="Play">
        <p>Some Button</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### 3. Решение через абсолютное позиционирование

```css
.container-fluid {
  height: 400px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.row{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5 text-center ">
      <div class="play-btn">
        <img src="http://elzol.lamusica.com/images/core/play.png" alt="Play">
        <p>Some Button</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>    
</div>
```

#### 4. Решение через line-height

```css
.container-fluid {
  height: 400px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.row{
  line-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5 text-center ">
      <div class="play-btn">
        <img src="http://elzol.lamusica.com/images/core/play.png" alt="Play">
        <p>Some Button</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>    
</div>
```